# Replaceall method is not working as expected. Literals are replaced twice instead

Tags: java

when I execute the below code, literals are being replaced twice

```
public  void  obify("CREATENEWABCDEFGHTNEW"){
        String _obiText=_obi;
        _obiText=_obiText.replaceAll("A","OBA");
        _obiText=_obiText.replaceAll("E","OBE");
        _obiText=_obiText.replaceAll("I","OBi");
        _obiText=_obiText.replaceAll("O","OBO");
        _obiText=_obiText.replaceAll("U","OBU");
        System.out.println(_obiText);
        }
```

Expected output: CROBEOBATOBENOBEWOBABCDOBEFGHTNOBEW ; Replace all the vowels with OB'Vowel Literal'
Actual output: CROBOBEOBOBATOBOBENOBOBEWOBOBABCDOBOBEFGHTNOBOBEW which is undesired and unexpcted.

Is there any other Java function to do the task I intended to do.

Comment: Have you tried moving  `_obiText.replaceAll("O","OBO");` to the top....?

Comment: All your replacement texts contain an O, then you write `_obiText=_obiText.replaceAll("O","OBO");`, which replaces all the Os.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. My mistake.

Comment: Why exactly did you undo my edit to again make your output examples less readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about replacing vowels?

```
_obiText = _obiText.replaceAll("[AEIOU]","OB$0");
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at what you're doing:

```
_obiText=_obiText.replaceAll("A","OBA");
```

here you replace all "A"s with "OBA"s. Fine, works well. Let's keep going.

```
_obiText=_obiText.replaceAll("E","OBE");
_obiText=_obiText.replaceAll("I","OBi");
```

All right, a little more...

```
_obiText=_obiText.replaceAll("O","OBO");
```

Here you mess up. You've replaced everything before with "OBx", being x the vowel. And of course, the same is happening to the "O"s that you and the replacements have written. So you get a longer text than you expected. The solution? Replace first the "O"s with "OBO"s and then everything else, then it will go fine.

PD: you can say that your result is undesired, as it's not what you want it to do, but not unexpected, because if you read and understand the code that's totally expected.